# Customize automatically generated TOC on jekyll site using toshimaru / jekyll-toc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I have a Jekyll site that uses https://github.com/toshimaru/jekyll-toc for right-side navigation. In _config.yml I have the following setting that ensures that only `<h2>` elements show up in the automatically generated table of contents.

```
toc:
  min_level: 2 # default: 1
  max_level: 2 # default: 6
```

This works fine, but on some pages, I would like to include `<h3>` elements in the toc as well.
So I want to change the max_level to 3 in a particular case. Is this possible? I want to change max_level value dynamically from the template code.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

At a glance it doesn't seem like that plugin supports per-page configuration. As a workaround, you could generate the third level headings all the time, and hide them with CSS unless you specifically show them on that page. The relevant parts:

layout:

```
<body class="{{ page.body_class }}">
```

page:

```
---
body_class: has-toc-level-3
---
```

css:

```
body:not(.has-toc-level-3) .toc-h3 {
  display: none;
}
```